# ObjectMapper properties set in a generic way?

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I am writing a class `JsonUtils` which will contain different functions to serialize and deserialize data.

```
 public class JsonUtils {

        private static final ObjectMapper JSON_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

        public static String toJsonString(Object obj)  {

            String json = null;

            JSON_MAPPER.setPropertyNamingStrategy(new CustomNamingStrategy());
            JSON_MAPPER.setSerializationInclusion(Inclusion.NON_NULL);

            try {
                System.out.print("OBJECT MAPPER:---> JSON STRING:\n" + JSON_MAPPER.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(obj));
                json = JSON_MAPPER.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(obj);
            } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return json;
        }

        public static <T> T toPOJO(String json, Class<T> type){

            JSON_MAPPER.setPropertyNamingStrategy(new CustomNameNamingStrategy());
            System.out.println("TO POJO: Json string " + json);
            try {

                return JSON_MAPPER.readValue(json, type);

            } catch (JsonParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Now, I want the functions to be used generically. For ex: someone wants to call `toJsonString` method but wants to use a different naming strategy to convert to json. Or may want to add some other properties to `ObjectMapper` like register a module.

Currently, the `ObjectMapper` properties are being set inside the function, thus a new naming strategy or a different property for `ObjectMapper` can't be used.

Is there a way that every user for `JsonUtils` initially sets it's own properties for `ObjectMapper` ? Or a efficient and generic way to write my Utility class ?

Comment: you can use jackson object mapper as it could be handy for your desired operation.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna: I am using jackson `ObjectMapper` itself. Which objectmapper are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

ObjectMapperProperties.java

```
package example;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy;

        public class ObjectMapperProperties {

            private PropertyNamingStrategy propertyNamingStrategy;

            private ObjectMapperProperties(final PropertyNamingStrategy propertyNamingStrategy) {
                this.propertyNamingStrategy = propertyNamingStrategy;
            }

            public PropertyNamingStrategy getPropertyNamingStrategy() {
                return propertyNamingStrategy;
            }

            public static class ObjectMapperPropertiesBuilder {

                private PropertyNamingStrategy builderPropertyNamingStrategy;

                public ObjectMapperPropertiesBuilder() {

                }

                public ObjectMapperPropertiesBuilder setPropertyNamingStrategy(final PropertyNamingStrategy builderPropertyNamingStrategy) {
                    this.builderPropertyNamingStrategy = builderPropertyNamingStrategy; 
                    return this;
                }

                public ObjectMapperProperties build() {
                    return new ObjectMapperProperties(builderPropertyNamingStrategy);
                }

            }
    }
```

ObjectMapperFactory.java

```
package example;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class ObjectMapperFactory {

    public static ObjectMapper getObjectMapper(final ObjectMapperProperties objectMapperProperties) {
        final ObjectMapper result = new ObjectMapper();
        result.setPropertyNamingStrategy(objectMapperProperties.getPropertyNamingStrategy());
        return result;
    }

}
```

Client.class

```
package example;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy;

import example.ObjectMapperProperties.ObjectMapperPropertiesBuilder;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectMapperPropertiesBuilder objectMapperPropertiesBuilder = new ObjectMapperPropertiesBuilder();
        objectMapperPropertiesBuilder.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
        ObjectMapperFactory factory = new ObjectMapperFactory();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = ObjectMapperFactory.getObjectMapper(objectMapperPropertiesBuilder.build());

    }

}
```

Than you could create ObjectMapper with setting as you need it. It doesn't have a sense and it's error-prone to set properties twice on already created instance.

```
private static final ObjectMapper JSON_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
JSON_MAPPER.setSerializationInclusion(Inclusion.NON_NULL);
```

so next time you need to reset this property for example, but to create new ObjectMapper() through some factory is priceless and less error-prone

Answers:

No you will create new instance of ObjectMapper through ObjectMapperFactory for each call and just pass the ObjectMapperProperties.

```
public static String toJsonString(Object obj,final ObjectMapperProperties objectMapperProperties)  {

ObjectMapper objectMapper = ObjectMapperFactory.getObjectMapper(objectMapperProperties);
}
```

In case you don't want to create new ObjectMapper instance and properties are final (mean you will always create ObjectMapper with same properties) than make a method.

```
public static String toJsonString(Object obj, ObjectMapper objMapper)  {}
```

Second question see [Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)

For better testing variation with Factory as interface will be helpful:

ObjectMapperFactory.class

```
public interface ObjectMapperFactory {

    public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper(final ObjectMapperProperties objectMapperProperties) {
}
```

Implementation of ObjectMapperFactory

ObjectMapperFactoryImpl.class

```
package example;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class ObjectMapperFactoryImpl implements ObjectMapperFactory {

    public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper(final ObjectMapperProperties objectMapperProperties) {
        final ObjectMapper result = new ObjectMapper();
        result.setPropertyNamingStrategy(objectMapperProperties.getPropertyNamingStrategy());
        return result;
    }

}
```

and in your class

```
 public class JsonUtils {

      private final ObjectMapperFactory objectMapperFactory;

      public JsonUtils(final ObjectMapperFactory objectMapperFactory) {
              this.objectMapperFactory = objectMapperFactory;
      }
}
```

But that is just a variantion. For your purposes answer posted above is enough.

Comment: So in every function I must pass the objectmapper instance ?

Comment: And here to add properties, I will have to add it in both `ObjectMapperProperties` and `ObjectMapperPropertiesBuilder`. Isn't that duplication?

Answer (score 0):

you can use hashmap and before call, from caller function first put some settings value like this

```
Map <String, String>settings = new HashMap<String, String>();
        settings.put("CUSTOM_NAMING_PROPERTY", "CAMEL_CASE");
```

and inside your function `toJsonString` you check the value.

```
    public static String toJsonString(Object obj,Map settings )  {

                String json = null;
                if(settings.get("CUSTOM_NAMING_PROPERTY")!=null){
                    //put your settings here.......
                }
                /////....... contd.....

                JSON_MAPPER.setSerializationInclusion(Inclusion.NON_NULL);

                try {
                    System.out.print("OBJECT MAPPER:---> JSON STRING:\n" + JSON_MAPPER.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(obj));
                    json = JSON_MAPPER.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(obj);
                } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return json;
            }
```

Comment: There are multiple properties in `ObjectMapper` like one can register a module to add `JsonSerailizer`, so this will lead to multiple parameters to functions. So this will lead to lot of parametres to the function

Comment: let's add a hashmap as a parameter, this may help here.

Comment: Will passing `ObjectMapper` instance to each function be a good idea? So every caller of the function will initialize the ObjectMapper according to its needs